# Laravel old input of selected option

Tags: php, laravel, validation, select, input

I know how to get the old input of a select option, but I have a problem with different languages.

Only two of six select options are not translated with `@lang('')` and for these two the `old('input')` works just fine.

Here is an example version of my select list:

```
<select name="color" class="form-control form-control-sm">
   <option value="4c" selected {{ old('color') == "4c" ? "selected" : "" }}>4c</option>
   <option value="s/w" {{ old('color') == "@lang('s/w')" ? "selected" : "" }}>@lang('s/w')</option>
   <option value="3c" {{ old('color') == "3c" ? "selected" : "" }}>3c</option>
   <option value="s/w + rot" {{ old('color') == "@lang('s/w + rot')" ? "selected" : "" }}>@lang('s/w + rot')</option>
   <option value="s/w + gelb" {{ old('color') == "@lang('s/w + gelb')" ? "selected" : "" }}>@lang('s/w + gelb')</option>
   <option value="s/w + blau" {{ old('color') == "@lang('s/w + blau')" ? "selected" : "" }}>@lang('s/w + blau')</option>
</select>
```

As you can see '4c' for example won't be translated since it has the same meaning in english while 's/w' will be translated to 'b/w' if necessary.

If I take option '3c' for example and the validation failed I will have '3c' as selected option. But when I take option 's/w' for e.g. and the validation of the form fails then the selected option will be '4c' (standard) again.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when you use it in a string the blade directive gets as a string but it is not getting evaluated, have you tried this instead:

```
{{ old('color') == trans('s/w + rot') ? "selected" : "" }}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I've already tried without putting quotation marks but used it with '@lang('..')' and this threw an exception, do you maybe know why?

Comment: Because when you use `{{ }}` the code in it is PHP code, and this `@lang` is a blade directive, so it cannot be used within `PHP`, but when you added quotes that got as string, and did not got the translation back. `trans()` is the php helper for getting translations.

Comment: This absolutely makes sense, I have to thank you! :)

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon please accept the answer my friend if it solved your issue :)

Comment: I will, just have to wait a minute to do so ._.